# Ionic 4 base64Image not showing in ion-image but showing in img

Tags: ionic4

I cannot figure out why `ion-image` is not displaying my base64 images from `Plugins.Camera.getPhoto()` but the `img` is able to render the image:

**my html**

```
<img *ngIf="selectedImage" [src]="selectedImage">
<ion-img
    role="button"
    class="image"
    (click)="onPickImage()"
    [src]="selectedImage"
    *ngIf="selectedImage"
></ion-img>
```

**my .ts**

```
    Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 50,
        source: CameraSource.Prompt,
        correctOrientation: true,
        height: 320,
        width: 200,
        resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl
    })
        .then(image => {
            this.selectedImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
                image && image.dataUrl
            );
            this.imagePick.emit(this.selectedImage);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

so what i see is :

[image]

as you can see the `ion-img` is not rendering the image

**EDIT**

this is the value i get in `selectedImage`:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz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

Comment: Please try to copy the ``base64`` hashed string and paste it inside ``ion-img`` as static image

Comment: it is not rendering, i also tried to convert base64 to image online and i am also not seeing an image. So there is obvisouly something wrong with my base64 string.

Comment: Can you paste it ?

Comment: the string is too long :) So i did an edit

Comment: i tried removing the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` and converting the rest online and that did not work

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  My guess is like me, you are following @Maximillian's Udemy Ionic course as I see that looks like the same code snippet.   Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yap, i was following the same course. Will post my work around just now

Comment: @ustad I just checked the code, i ended up using <img class="image" *ngIf="selectedImage" [src]="selectedImage" role="button" (click)="onPickImage()">

Comment: Thanks @JustLearning looks like <ion-img> component doesn't work and we have to use the plain <img> selector.  You'll also find that in some versions of Android there is a bug with the pic orientation (even when setting correctOrientation: true) but in iOS its fine.

Comment: Any one find a solution ? using img we are loosing the ability to render on demand feature !